# Objective-c: how to sort a NSMutableArray of UIButtons using their tags

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios4, ios5

I have a NSMutableArray containing UIButtons. I have given each of the buttons a unique
tag. The buttons will be added to the array in random order, but i want to later sort it so that the buttons are in ascending order with respect to their tags.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: If the problem is solved, you should check your question as solved and choose an answer to help people in the future with the same problem :)

Answer (score 6):

Yeap.

Try this:

```
NSSortDescriptor *ascendingSort = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"tag" ascending:YES];
NSSortDescriptor *descendingSort = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"tag" ascending:NO];
NSArray *sortedArray = [someArray sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:ascendingSort]];
```

Comment: Obviously you need to use either the ascendingSort or the descending NSSortDescriptor

Answer (score 2):

You can use the NSSortDescriptor to sort a NSArray.

```
NSArray *unsortedArray = ...
NSArray *sortedArray = [unsortedArray sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"tag" ascending:YES]]];
```

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple "sortedArrayUsing..." functions.  Use the one that seems to fit your needs the best.

(BTW, remember that, since NSMutableArray is a subclass of NSArray, all of the methods of NSArray apply to NSMutableArray as well.)